# Selenium getText

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, gettext, getattribute

I want to `getText()` using `By.id` or `By.cssSelector`.

I managed to solve my problem by doing `getAttribute("value")`, but I don't understand why `getText()` doesn't work like I expect it, and I might need it so all help is appreciated.

Here is the Java code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
Boolean elementIsPresent = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementValue(By.cssSelector("#general_service_name"),"[reg] general_service_name")); // true

//WebElement general_service_name = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#general_service_name"));
WebElement general_service_name = driver.findElement(By.id("general_service_name"));

// Display check
Boolean isDisplayed;
if(general_service_name.isDisplayed())  isDisplayed = new Boolean(true); else isDisplayed = false; //true

String text_empty = general_service_name.getText(); //""
String text_with_value = driver.findElement(By.id("general_service_name")).getAttribute("value"); //"[reg] general_service_name"
```

And HTML:

```
<input id="general_service_name" type="text" value="[reg] title" name="general_service_name" style="float:left;"/>
```

Comment: getText returns only visible text and does NOT return any HTML elements and does NOT return any hidden text. For example, with Java I was having this issue with a BR tag returning empty. Instead of `.getText()` I used `.getAttribute("innerHTML")` which will then return what I was looking for, including any HTML that is invisible or text that is hidden.

Comment: @jsherk: But that is not what *this* question is about(?).

Comment: @PeterMortensen - Well yes it sort of is because the op said "but I don't understand why getText() doesn't work like I expect it" and the reason is because getText returns text only with no HTML elements whereas getAttribute will return the html elements along with the text. But I did respond as a comment as opposed to an answer because its only partially what the question is about.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getText()

getText() delivers the innerText of a WebElement.

Your input field does not have any inner Text. The text is found inside your value-attribute, hence accessing it via getAttribute("value") is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Java
`ele.getAttribute("innerHTML");`

This could get the text already in the background and not displayed on the page yet.

Comment: This was really helpful in a situation where getText() returned an empty string but your solution returned the inner Text of the <svg><title> element. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer - it's designed this way. `getText()` parses the content of the tag (i.e. its innerText), which is obviously empty for inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this if you want to search for a given text on a WebElement. Pass it directly or through a string:

```
String textoToSearch = "Text inside Webelement";
driver.findElement(By.id("someID).getText().contains("textToSearch");
```

Comment: What is `WebElement`? Is it literal?

Answer (score 0):

### getText()

[`getText()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getText()) returns the visible text of this element.

```
java.lang.String getText()
Get the visible (i.e. not hidden by CSS) text of this element, including sub-elements.


Returns:
The visible text of this element.
```

---

As per the HTML of the element:

```
<input id="general_service_name" type="text" value="[reg] title" name="general_service_name" style="float:left;"/>
```

The [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) doesn't have a visible text but the `value` attribute have the value set as `[reg] title`.

So to extract the value of the `value` attribute i.e. `[reg] title` you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  System.out.println(wd.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#general_service_name[name='general_service_name']")).getAttribute("value"));
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  System.out.println(wd.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='general_service_name' and @name='general_service_name']")).getAttribute("value"));
  ```

---

Ideally, you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *cssSelector* and `getText()`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input#general_service_name[name='general_service_name']"))).getAttribute("value"));
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `getAttribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='general_service_name' and @name='general_service_name']"))).getAttribute("value"));
  ```