# Why is getText() in Selenium not working for <textarea> elements, but getAttribute("value") is?

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Given you have some HTML with a textarea element and want to get its text via Selenium (here Java-binding).

```
<textarea name="txtComment" id="txtComment" rows="2" cols="20">
    Some comment inside the textarea
</textarea>
```

This is how I see the code via developer tools (Internet Explorer and Firefox), so it seems like it is a normal text-node and not inside the "value" attribute of the element.

Why is it then that **getText() does not work**:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("txtComment")).getText();
```

It only *returns an empty String*.

*But* using **getAttribute("value") works** and results in returning the expected string:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("txtComment")).getAttribute("value");
```

This *returns "Some comment inside the textarea" as expected*

This is rather surprising since the Selenium documentation about [getText()](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getText%28%29) says the following:

> Get the visible (i.e. not hidden by CSS) innerText of this element,
> including sub-elements, without any leading or trailing whitespace.
>
> Returns:
> The innerText of this element.

As the HTML code in the beginning shows, the text-part of the element is visible and it is the "innerText", isn't it?

#### Can someone shed light on where I'm wrong or if I'm not, why is this implemented like this in Selenium?

Comment: Because getText returns a text node. Input and textarea element text is stored in the value attribute so you need to retrieve the "value" attribute's data.

Comment: yeah but when I use the developer tools of some browsers (ie, firefox) I see the code as posted in my question -> so seems that it is a textnode, isn't it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? *[Selenium getText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23804123/selenium-gettext)*

Answer (score 2):

In Python, it gives the same result:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("txtComment").text
driver.find_element_by_id("txtComment").get_attribute("value")
```

Some comment inside the textarea.

Comment: But that is not the case for form `input` elements (for the actual user input)

Comment: Does `.text` really get the inner text of `textarea`? I would expect `.text` to always return an empty string. What did you test it on (incl. versions)?

Comment: It is not true. In python I get the same behaviour .text returns empty string, where .get_attribute("value") returns string value

Answer (score 1):

With Webdriverio (WDIO) tried the same thing.

getText() not worked on Textarea. Returned blank String.

Used getValue() instead, worked for me. Returned the exact string.

`<textarea id="txtAreaDescription" maxlength="2500" class="css-pqtyuc">Auto_Internal_Note_Description</textarea>`